# How to transform this to UTF-8?

Tags: php, utf-8, transform

character `İ` is is defined as `&#x130;`

how can I transform this to UTF-8?

I was transforming `&#304;` to `İ` with str_replace but I couldn't find `&#x130;` list to transform.

Answer (score 0):

```
iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", 'YOUR_CHARACTER_HERE')
```

Comment: what does it mean 'your_character_here'?
i dont know what character set is it, i'm taking datas with curl. how can i learn it? thx for answer

Comment: I've found the solution: html_entity_decode($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');